# Select item from PowerShell hashtable without using Foreach

Tags: powershell

I have this list of `PSObjects`, each of which contains a `Hashtable`. Currently I can get it out like this:

`foreach ($item in $myListOfItems) { $item.Metadata["Title"] }`

However, I am wondering if I can do it somehow with piping and `Select`. Is this possible?  For example:

`$myListOfItems | Select $_.Metadata["Title"]`

...which only outputs a whole bunch of blank lines :(

Any ideas? Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about

```
$myListOfItems | select @{ Label="Title";Expression={$_.Metadata["Title"]}}
```

Comment: I admit it works, although I was hoping for something shorter than the original :(

Comment: Something shorter would be this but it's using foreach-object (%): `$myListOfItems| % {$_.metadata['title']}`

Comment: How can I get the output of several keys of the hashtable and group them? I have Metadata.title, Metadata.detail, etc. The `title` key appears several times, I want to group it so that title is unique and add the `details`(one or more) to each `title`?

Answer (score 3):

The original idea was **close** but just got the syntax wrong. To use `$_`, the expression must be within a script-block parameter (Powershell V3+):

```
 $myListOfItems | select { $_.Metadata["title"] }
```

Without the enclosing script-block, `$_` is evaluated in the context of the whole pipeline instead of the pipeline element (`Select-Object` in this case). At this level, `$_` is not defined so evaluates to `$null`. PowerShell is somewhat forgiving about using `$null` inappropriately. In particular, attempting to retrieve a property of `$null` is not an error, it just returns `$null`. So `$null.Metadata["title"]` → `$null["title"]` → `$null`. `Select-Object $null` just outputs an empty selection object for each input object thus resulting in the blank lines.

It should be noted that, strictly speaking, neither the originally suggested `Select-Object` (as fixed) nor the hash table version in the answer provide the same output as the `ForEach` loop. The loop produces a sequence of values from the `.Metadata["Title"]` members while `Select-Object` produces a sequence of selection objects `[Selected.System.Collections.Hashtable]` each containing a member (named `$_.Metadata["Title"]` and `Title` respectively) which holds the value. Whether this causes a problem depends on the usage.

For a really short version, try:

```
$myListOfItems.Metadata.Title
```

Since PowerShell V3, specifying a non-existent member of a collection causes Powershell to perform a *member enumeration*<sup>†</sup> whereby it would enumerate the collection and return a sequence of values of the specified member of each element of the collection (assuming there is one). If we assume left to right evaluation then the expression would be evaluated as:

```
($myListOfItems.Metadata).Title
```

Firstly enumerating the collection of items, as it has no Metadata member. Each item does have a Metadata member thus resulting in an `Array` of the Metadata members. Then this collection of Metadata hashtables, having no Title member, is enumerated to produce an `Array` of the Title elements of the hashtables.

† I think the term *member enumeration* is somewhat misleading. It is not the members which are being enumerated but the objects in the collection and an `Array` of the specified member of each object is then created. Indeed, even though the manual [about_Hash_Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables) states that the hash table has properties named after the keys with corresponding values, this is actually just Powershell shorthand for invoking the indexer `[]` (which actually appears to override member access so beware of hash tables with keys "Count", "Keys", "Values", ... if you want to access the **actual** hash table members of these names). So, strictly speaking, there is no 'Title' member. The term "enumerated collection member access" (ECMA ;) would better describe what is happening but after all "A rose by any other name".